# Install teradatasql for R 4.0.2

Tags: r, teradata, teradatasql

I try to install teradatasql as explained here:
https://github.com/Teradata/r-driver#Installation

However, it immediately throws this error:

```
install.packages('teradatasql',repos=c('https://teradata-download.s3.amazonaws.com','https://cloud.r-project.org'))
Installing package into ‘/home/ckiefer/RProjects/cki_new_db_interface/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.0.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://teradata-download.s3.amazonaws.com/src/contrib:
Line starting '<?xml version="1.0"  ...' is malformed!
Warning message:
package ‘teradatasql’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

So, it cannot be installed for this version of R although it says that the package requires 64-bit R 3.4.3 or later?

Any help is appreciated.

BR, Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **teradatasql** installation should work okay with R 4.0.2. I just successfully tested it myself using R 4.0.2 for Windows.

Google found the following topic related to your error message:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-packages-unable-to-access-index-for-repository-try-disabling-secure-download-method-for-http/16578